# How to get JSON key for d3.js chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Here is my problem : I an array with JSON object in it ad I would like to get the keys of JSON objects to build a bar chart with it.

Here is my array :

```
var dataset = [{
      "T1": 4.23
    },
    {
      "T2": 45.62
    },
    {
      "T3": 24.78
    },
    {
      "T4": 11.41
    },
    {
      "T5": 5.19
    },
    {
      "T6": 5.15
    },
    {
      "T7": 1.99
    },
    {
      "T8": 0.93
    },
    {
      "T9": 0.61
    }
  ];
```

And here is my code to draw the chart :

```
  let width = 500;
  let heigth = 200;
  let barPadding = 1;

  let svg = d3.select("#containerChart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", heigth);


  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
      return i + (20 + barPadding);
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
      return heigth - (**values of JSON object** * 2)
    })
    .att("width", 20)
    .attr("heigth", function (d) {
      return (**values of JSON object** * 2)
    })
    .attr("fill", "teal")
```

Do you have any idea of how I could do ?

Thanks in advance for your help !!

Comment: Well, to get the "keys" of any javascript object, use `Object.keys(obj)` -- but in your case you have an array of objects, each with its own special key. Are you trying to get a list of all the unique keys from the array?

Comment: FYI: it's height, not heigth... In any case, `**values of JSON object**` seems to indicate you want the values, not the keys, as it doesn't make sense to to multiply "T1" by 2. Do you want the number of keys? The sum of the values?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/tgiachett/pen/KevxRL) and here's the code for testing on your local:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <style>

  .bar{
    fill: steelblue;
  }

  .bar:hover{
    fill: brown;
  }

    .axis {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
// set the dimensions of the canvas
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


// set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// define the axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);


// add the SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


// load the data
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {


  // scale the range of the data
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return Object.keys(d); }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d[Object.keys(d)]; })]);

  // add axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 5)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

  // Add bar chart
  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Object.keys(d)); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(+d[Object.keys(d)]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(+d[Object.keys(d)]); });

});

</script>

</body>
```

I replaced all references for the y axis with the json keys using Object.keys() and got the values for these keys to put into the x axis. You could also use `for... in` loop to do the same thing.

To test it locally, you will have to host both files on a local server or else you will get CORS errors. You could include a parsed inline json to avoid CORS altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work :

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
      return i + (20 + barPadding);
    })
    .attr("y", function (d,i) {

      return heigth - d["T" + (i+1)]
    })
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("heigth", function (d,i) {
      return heigth - d["T" + (i+1)]
    })
    .attr("fill", "teal")
```